# C# Windows Phone app Sending a file via Bluetooth

Tags: c#, networking, bluetooth, windows-phone

I am developing Windows Phone 8 app where as I need to send a file from one device to another using Bluetooth. I need help with the piece of code that does so. I did not find any code via forums or Stack Overflow. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

another one, a [sample app](http://blog.%41pitron.com/2014/01/send-file-via-bluetooth-windows-phone-winrt.html) that sends file via bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

You can find some sample code on the [MSDN Windows Phone samples page](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/).

Here are two Bluetooth samples I found:

- [Bluetooth app to app sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Bluetooth-app-to-app-sample-890f8303)
- [Bluetooth app to device sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Bluetooth-app-to-device-644870ba)